# FastAPI - CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, fastapi

in my FastAPI, I am trying to implement Google OAuth2 using the authlib library.

I am registering the client like so:

```
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name="google",
    client_id=settings.google_client_id,
    client_secret=settings.google_client_secret,
    authorize_url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
)
```

Additionally, I am adding the SessionMiddleware which is essential for this to work properly:

```
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="gcp_oauth", https_only=True)>
```

I have 2 endpoints for handling the authorization like so:

```
    async def login():
        authorization_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
        params = {
            "client_id": settings.google_client_id,
            "response_type": "code",
            "scope": "openid profile email",
            "redirect_uri": settings.redirect_uri,
        }
        redirect_url = f"{authorization_url}?{'&'.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in params.items())}"
        return RedirectResponse(url=redirect_url)

    @app.get("/login/callback")
    async def login_callback(request: Request):
        token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
        user = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, token)
        return user
```

When I go to / I am getting prompt to log in with Google and everything is almost alright. I get the following error on the redirect:

```
authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response."
```

Comment: I have similar error. Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just had this problem; there were 2 issues at play

1. the mismatch tokens is because your browser is holding an old token
2. watch out for redirecting improperly between http and https

I was able to get the proper redirect using an incognito browser.